# check if checkbox checked using ngcheck doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the logic but I'm facing problems to continue.

mouseenter/mouseleave to show/hide checkbox, if checkbox checked deactive the mouse and leave function to make the checkbox stay visible.

my code and demo http://plnkr.co/edit/LdBbWzbpKC1TSR7faslf?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx19bbWGmuovMhVW62PC?p=preview

```
<input ng-show="showC || checked" type="checkbox" 
       id="{{$index}}" ng-model="checked">
```

Comment: @user3522457 then how about marking this as your answer if it helped you?